# Can gRPC and gRPC-Web be used at the same time in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-web

We are building a frontend written in React and at the same time, we have multiple backend systems written in C#. Is it possible to host the same ASP.NET gRPC services using normal gRPC and gRPC-Web at the same time? So the service can be called from both JS frontend and backend services in C#.

Comment: I think you should be able to simply enable grpc web in your existing Grpc.AspNetCore.Server and everthing will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible.

If you're using Envoy or something similar, the Envoy gRPC-Web filter can be at a gateway which will proxy incoming HTTP/1 requests, while other services can send requests to the gRPC service (without going through the gateway).

If you're using an in-language proxy, then your server will need to accept both HTTP/1 which will be proxied, as well as gRPC over HTTP/2.